# got an error when using command cat followed by grep and then cut

Tags: linux, bash, command

I have a file containing a list of file names. I want to read the content of the file and filter it with the following command:

```bash
cat list.txt | grep ' jane ' | cut -d ' ' -f 3
```

When I run the command, I got an error

```
cut: you must specify a list of bytes, characters, or fields
Try 'cut --help' for more information.
```

The content of the file is following:

```
001 jane /data/jane_profile_07272018.doc
002 kwood /data/kwood_profile_04022017.doc
003 pchow /data/pchow_profile_05152019.doc
004 janez /data/janez_profile_11042019.doc
005 jane /data/jane_pic_07282018.jpg
006 kwood /data/kwood_pic_04032017.jpg
007 pchow /data/pchow_pic_05162019.jpg
008 jane /data/jane_contact_07292018.csv
009 kwood /data/kwood_contact_04042017.csv
010 pchow /data/pchow_contact_05172019.csv
```

Goal: I only want the path to file which is the third column.

Comment: This is a perfect job for awk: `awk '$2=="jane"{print $3}' list.txt`

Comment: @Mat it works perfectly. Thanks, but any ideas on how to do the same using grep and cut? That would be much appreciated

Comment: There's nothing obvously wrong with the command you show. Are you sure it exacty matches what you are actually using?

Comment: I think you are inadvertently using a different (maybe Microsoft) `cut` from that which you are expecting. Try `... grep ... | /usr/bin/cut ...`

Comment: @MarkSetchell it exactly matches one of coreutils cut error messages

Comment: @jhnc I thought so, but I tried so many times, and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found:

```bash
grep ' jane ' list.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 3
```